# Mysql- exclude the rows which are having same minutes

Tags: mysql

I want the excluded result of rows which are having same minutes

Example: customers table

```
id date
1 2015-07-23 00:06:56
2 2015-07-23 00:11:38
3 2015-07-23 01:10:16
4 2015-07-23 01:10:13
5 2015-07-24 01:13:26
6 2015-07-24 01:13:13
```

**I want the query to exclude id's: 3, 4, 5 & 6 because (3 & 4) and (5 & 6) are having same minutes**

So expected result is:

```
id date
1 2015-07-23 00:06:56
2 2015-07-23 00:11:38
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to filter out _all_ duplicate minutes regardless of date, or do you want to remove duplicates only within a given hour for a given day?

Comment: Duplicate date except the seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out. Subquery finds out the hour and minutes that are duplicated. Outer query selects all records except the one returned by the subquery.

```
select *
from customers
where date_format(dt, '%H%i') not in
(
  select date_format(dt, '%H%i')
  from customers a
  group by date_format(dt, '%H%i')
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88a24/4

**Filter out duplicate hour + minute by day**

```
select *
from test
where date_format(dt, '%Y%j%H%i') not in
(
  select date_format(dt, '%Y%j%H%i')
  from test a
  group by date_format(dt, '%Y%j%H%i')
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2da/2

Another example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eeaf/1 (using data from updated question)

Comment: Will this filter out _all_ duplicated minute records for _any_ date, or will it remove duplicates for a given day and hour (and the OP was not clear about this BTW)?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, this filters out all duplicate hhmm (hour minute) combination regardless of day.

Comment: If we wanted to filter out duplicate hour+min combination by day, we can use `date_format(dt, '%Y%j%H%i')` instead - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2da/2)

Comment: @zedfoxus, thank you for the answer. is it possible to check between two different dates instead of checking for one day ? Question updated.

Comment: @Asik check out the edited answer `Filter out duplicate hour + minute by day` with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2da/2 example

Answer (score 1):

You can form a group using the year, day, hour and minute portions of the `date` column, and then only retain groups which have one record.  This filters out all records which have duplicate minutes.  Then I `JOIN` this temporary table back to your customers table for the result.  This solution does not use a subquery.

```
SELECT id, date
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date),
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date),
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t
ON c.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from tablename
group by date
having count(*)=1
```